# Java Email Exception -- Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: java, email, exception

This error is driving me nuts.  I'm trying to send myself emails when my application throws exceptions but I just started getting this error.  I am able to successfully ping the host and I can get a local ip address when I use nslookup.  Any ideas?  Thanks

```
        try
    {
        java.util.Date d = new Date();
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "My server address");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        Authenticator authenticator = new SmtpAuthenticator();

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("My email"));
        message.setSubject("Voicemail Notification");
        message.setContent("You are receiving this automatic message because there has been a voicemail left in the system on " +d.toString() + " for the division of the company you work for. \n" +
        "Please respond promptly.  Thanks!\n" +
        "Private Ip address?file=" + messageName + ".gsm", "text/plain");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTo));
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Email Sent!");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to send email notification to: " + emailTo);
    }
```

Comment: Can you use telnet to connect to `telnet mailserver 25` ?

Comment: @MitchDempsey, you should add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.  I made a stupid mistake.  Jumped the gun and posted a question but your comment helped.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using command line to try `telnet mailserveraddress 25` this will tell you whether or not the mail server is actually running and listening on port 25. If you receive the same error in telnet, then that means your mail server is not running properly.